# SORT, ORDER by Number

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
ID     Name    Items
------------------------------------- 
1      John    7
2      Peter   533
3      Chang   13
4      Mike    9100
```

I want to order it by Items. I used ORDER BY items ASC, but it returns:

```
ID     Name    Items
------------------------------------- 
3      Chang   13
2      Peter   533
1      John    7
4      Mike    9100
```

I want to return:

```
ID     Name    Items
------------------------------------- 
1      John    7
3      Chang   13
2      Peter   533
4      Mike    9100
```

I think this might be a silly question, but I really don't have any ideas about how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: The order you desire doesn't seem to make any sense, can you explain the "rules" for why the numbers should come back in that order?

Comment: As an aside, it seem you have the items being stored as character data instead of numeric data, not sure if that's really what you want.

Comment: xzilla thanks. My bad, Items type was VARCHAR. Now it returns desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only explanation I can think of that result, if you are sorting with `Order By Items ASC` as you said, is that `Items` column is of character datatype (either `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`) instead of numeric.

`13, 533, 7, 9100` are in lexicographical order, not numerical order.

Check the data type of that column.

Comment: yes you r right for that.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, Items type was VARCHAR.I changed it to INT. Now it returns desired result.